# Is it possible to control horizontal letter spacing in Vim?

Tags: fonts, vim

Is it possible to control horizontal letter spacing in Vim (Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim is a text editor, not a word processor or publishing package so there isn't such a feature.

Comment: Are you suggesting that text editors do not space letters horizontally?  If so, this is indeed bizarre and factually incorrect.  Typical SE...

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but if you change the font for your terminal window your font in vim will change as well. So what you need is a widely-spaced monospace font. Try OCR B (the spacing between letters is very wide):

http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/ocr-b-10/

You may already have it installed, and/or it may be available from other sources.